# Xdebug failed to run in php 7 in debug mode

Tags: php, xdebug

I have compiled xdebug it added it to php.ini but this happens.

```
/opt/php/sbin/php-fpm 
NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/xdebug.so' - /opt/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0 , my php is in debug mode.
```

What should I do?

**Edit**

If I place the file inside the directory this other error happens:

/opt/php/sbin/php-fpm

```
NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/xdebug.so' - /opt/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: _zval_ptr_dtor_wrapper in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: fix your config to you have the right paths for that xdebug.so, or make sure it IS in that directory.

Comment: The second error happens because I'm using a non-debug .so in a debug build. Don't know how to overcome this (make it build in debug mode)

Comment: your xdebug was compiled for a different version of php. you generally can never mix/match .so files for different php versions.